# For loop stuck at same point in array shifter

Tags: java, arrays

The method is supposed to take an array of ints, an integer value, and an integer index. The method should insert the value at the given index and move the values afterward by one.

For example this
`insertValue(a, 100, 2)` would change the array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` to `{1, 2, 100, 3, 4}`

This is the code I'm using to execute the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] and = {4,2,6,1,4,3,4};
    insertValue(and, 100, 2);
}
```

This is the method itself:

```
public static void insertValue(int[] a,int b , int c) {
    for(int i = c; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        a[i+1] = a[i];
        System.out.print(a[i]);
    } 
    a[c] = b;
    System.out.print(a[c]);
}
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
6666100
```

So not only is it stuck one one number, it is also stopping in the wrong spot. This is for a homework assignment, so an explanation on where I went wrong would be helpful.

Comment: Tell me: if I do `int[] a = {4,2,6,1,4,3,4}; a[4] = a[3]; a[5] = a[4]; a[6] = a[5];` what numbers does `a` contain after this?

Comment: I get this as the output: 6111100

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: each time you set `a[i+1] = a[i];` will effect your next loop

Comment: Do a top to `c+1` loop and insert `b` at c

Answer (score 1):

Since the array length is 7, `b` is 2 and `n` is 100, your method does this:

```
      // array originally contains {4,2,6,1,4,3,4}
a[3] = a[2];
             // array now contains {4,2,6,6,4,3,4}
System.out.print(a[2]); // prints 6
a[4] = a[3];
             // array now contains {4,2,6,6,6,3,4}
System.out.print(a[3]); // prints 6
a[5] = a[4];
             // array now contains {4,2,6,6,6,6,4}
System.out.print(a[4]); // prints 6
a[6] = a[5];
             // array now contains {4,2,6,6,6,6,6}
System.out.print(a[5]); // prints 6
a[2] = 100;
             // array now contains {4,2,100,6,6,6,6}
System.out.print(a[100]); // prints 100
```

This is why you get the output `6666100`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = c; i < a.length-1; i++) {
    a[i+1] = a[i];
    System.out.print(a[i]);
}
```

Is trying to copy the "end" of the array to make space for the new item.
If `c=2` then the loop is saying:

- `a[3] = a[2]`
- `a[4] = a[3]`
- `a[5] = a[6]`

In other words, you are writing over the contents of the array as you go - you copy index 3 into 4, but now you have lost 4 so you can't copy 4 to 5 (because it's value is overwritten)

The easiest way to do it is to start from the end and pull values "to the right" as you work down towards `c`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the end of the array and work backwards copying the elements, until you reach the replacement index. Then insert the element at that index. Below loop should be able to o that:

```
for(int i = a.length - 2; i >= c; i--){
    a[i+1] = a[i];
    System.out.println(a[i]);
} 
a[c] = b;
```